# Remove view which is not associated with List from RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, view, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerViewAdapter` with 2 item types. `ItemViewHolder` for all itemViews in `ArrayList` and `HeaderViewHolder` for one headerView. I can remove item from `ArrayList` and then use `notifyItemRemoved(position)` in order to remove itemView from `RecyclerView`. But how do I remove headerView which is not associated with the `ArrayList`?

Below is some code from `RecyclerViewAdapter`:

```
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
private List<Offer> mValues;
OfferListAdapter(List<String> items) {
        mValues = items;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemView, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(v);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.headerView, parent, false);
            return new HeaderViewHolder(v);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {
            ItemViewHolder userViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
        } else if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
             HeaderViewHolder headerViewHolder= (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;

        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    private Offer getItem(int position) {
        return mValues.get(position - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size() + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HeaderView *is* part of your list, at least from the adapters point of view.

You say `isPositionHeader(pos -> pos == 0)` to indicate that the first item of your list is the header view, and you tell the adapter your list has `mValues.size() + 1` items in it. The `+1` to make up for the header which comes first.

So how could you remove this view again?

---

If you want to toggle it on / off...you need something that can toggle between states. Why not use a `boolean`? You could have some `isShowingHeader` field that indicates whether or not the header gets displayed.

How would this affect your code? Well...the same code as above...

```
// if we show the header, the 0 position is the header
isPositionHeader(pos -> isShowingHeader && pos == 0)
```

And for your list size...

```
// list is longer by 1 when showing a header
mValues.size() + (isShowingHeader ? 1 : 0)
```

When showing / hiding your header you now only have to update `isShowingHeader` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to notify the adapter of your changed values.

Comment: You made my day, again